# ActiveMQ Artemis master does not failback after container restart in cloud environment

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm trying to setup simple artemis failover support on docker swarm with two nodes.
I can see that backup takes over when master is stopped but the new master never manages to take over from the backup.

The nodes are EC2 instances sharing a security group that allow members of the same security group to connect to any port over TCP and UDP.

What could be the problem?

Note: `broker.xml` looks exactly like out-of-the-box except my snipped below added.

`Docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  artemis:
    image: apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine
    environment:
      ARTEMIS_USER: "artemis"
      ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: "artemis"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      endpoint_mode: vip
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    volumes:
      - ./broker-artemis-master.xml:/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc-override/broker.xml
  artemis-slave:
    image: apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine
    environment:
      ARTEMIS_USER: "artemis"
      ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: "artemis"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      endpoint_mode: vip
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
    volumes:
      - ./broker-artemis-slave.xml:/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc-override/broker.xml
```

from `broker-artemis-master.xml`

```xml
      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <master>
               <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            </master>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <connectors>
         <connector name="artemis-slave">tcp://artemis-slave:61616</connector>
         <connector name="artemis">tcp://artemis:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>artemis-slave</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

from `broker-artemis-slave.xml`:

```xml
     <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <slave>
               <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
               <max-saved-replicated-journals-size>0</max-saved-replicated-journals-size>
            </slave>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <connectors>
         <connector name="artemis-slave">tcp://artemis-slave:61616</connector>
         <connector name="artemis">tcp://artemis:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
         <connector-ref>artemis-slave</connector-ref>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

Error-message from master from the new container replacing stopped container

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-6 ~]$ docker container logs 0800bf7b7bb8
CREATE_ARGUMENTS=--user artemis --password artemis --silent --require-login --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia
Creating ActiveMQ Artemis instance at: /var/lib/artemis-instance

Auto tuning journal ...
done! Your system can make 7.14 writes per millisecond, your journal-buffer-timeout will be 140000

You can now start the broker by executing:

   "/var/lib/artemis-instance/bin/artemis" run

Or you can run the broker in the background using:

   "/var/lib/artemis-instance/bin/artemis-service" start

copying file to etc folder: broker.xml
     _        _               _
    / \  ____| |_  ___ __  __(_) _____
   / _ \|  _ \ __|/ _ \  \/  | |/  __/
  / ___ \ | \/ |_/  __/ |\/| | |\___ \
 /_/   \_\|   \__\____|_|  |_|_|/___ /
 Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.31.2


2023-12-18 09:42:53,660 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server version 2.31.2
2023-12-18 09:42:53,756 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2023-12-18 09:42:59,267 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2023-12-18 09:42:59,289 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222007: Security risk! Apache ActiveMQ Artemis is running with the default cluster admin user and default password. Please see the cluster chapter in the ActiveMQ Artemis User Guide for instructions on how to change this.
2023-12-18 09:42:59,381 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1073741824
2023-12-18 09:42:59,461 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2023-12-18 09:42:59,462 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2023-12-18 09:42:59,463 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2023-12-18 09:42:59,463 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2023-12-18 09:42:59,464 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2023-12-18 09:42:59,465 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2023-12-18 09:42:59,706 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
2023-12-18 09:42:59,725 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
2023-12-18 09:42:59,826 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2023-12-18 09:42:59,828 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
2023-12-18 09:43:00,402 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2023-12-18 09:43:00,427 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5445 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]
2023-12-18 09:43:00,438 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5672 for protocols [AMQP]
2023-12-18 09:43:00,452 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:1883 for protocols [MQTT]
2023-12-18 09:43:00,461 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61613 for protocols [STOMP]
2023-12-18 09:43:00,461 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2023-12-18 09:43:00,462 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.31.2 [0.0.0.0, nodeID=d0fdfaf5-9d89-11ee-a30d-0242ac120004]
2023-12-18 09:43:00,484 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241003: Starting embedded web server
2023-12-18 09:43:00,509 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212007: connector.create or connectorFactory.createConnector should never throw an exception, implementation is badly behaved, but we will deal with it anyway.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:874) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:866) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:848) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1212) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1333) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1253) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1496) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1074) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:959) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:279) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:633) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:618) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:602) ~[artemis-core-client-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionBridge.createSessionFactory(ClusterConnectionBridge.java:168) ~[artemis-server-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.connect(BridgeImpl.java:942) ~[artemis-server-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl$ConnectRunnable.run(BridgeImpl.java:1145) ~[artemis-server-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:57) ~[artemis-commons-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:32) ~[artemis-commons-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.31.2.jar:2.31.2]
2023-12-18 09:43:00,554 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224091: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@4680900b [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@20592c91 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@4680900b [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@20592c91 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=-1&host=null], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1322907569[nodeUUID=d0fdfaf5-9d89-11ee-a30d-0242ac120004, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=artemis, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=-1&host=null], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is unable to connect to destination. Retrying
```

logs from slave refusing to be replaced by master:

```
     _        _               _
    / \  ____| |_  ___ __  __(_) _____
   / _ \|  _ \ __|/ _ \  \/  | |/  __/
  / ___ \ | \/ |_/  __/ |\/| | |\___ \
 /_/   \_\|   \__\____|_|  |_|_|/___ /
 Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.31.2


2023-12-18 09:23:55,343 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server version 2.31.2
2023-12-18 09:23:55,420 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: backup Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2023-12-18 09:23:55,446 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241003: Starting embedded web server
2023-12-18 09:23:55,452 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221059: Deleting old data directory /var/lib/artemis-instance/data/journal as the max folders is set to 0
2023-12-18 09:23:55,539 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2023-12-18 09:23:55,625 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222007: Security risk! Apache ActiveMQ Artemis is running with the default cluster admin user and default password. Please see the cluster chapter in the ActiveMQ Artemis User Guide for instructions on how to change this.
2023-12-18 09:23:55,722 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1073741824
2023-12-18 09:23:55,949 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2023-12-18 09:23:55,951 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2023-12-18 09:23:55,952 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2023-12-18 09:23:55,956 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2023-12-18 09:23:55,958 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2023-12-18 09:23:55,959 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2023-12-18 09:23:56,342 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2023-12-18 09:23:56,452 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2023-12-18 09:23:56,834 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2023-12-18 09:23:56,860 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2023-12-18 09:23:56,862 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.17.6
2023-12-18 09:23:56,871 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2023-12-18 09:23:56,881 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginRedirectFilter] Hawtio loginRedirectFilter is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2023-12-18 09:23:56,896 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2023-12-18 09:23:56,904 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/var/lib/artemis-instance/./etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2023-12-18 09:23:57,050 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8161
2023-12-18 09:23:57,053 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console/jolokia
2023-12-18 09:23:57,054 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console
2023-12-18 09:23:58,511 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221109: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Backup Server version 2.31.2 [null] started, waiting live to fail before it gets active
2023-12-18 09:23:59,932 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221024: Backup server ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0 is synchronized with live server, nodeID=2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403.
2023-12-18 09:23:59,942 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221031: backup announced
2023-12-18 09:25:02,613 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222295: There is a possible split brain on nodeID 2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403. Topology update ignored
2023-12-18 09:25:02,614 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221066: Initiating quorum vote: LiveFailoverQuorumVote
2023-12-18 09:25:02,615 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221084: Requested 0 quorum votes
2023-12-18 09:25:02,615 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221083: ignoring quorum vote as max cluster size is 1.
2023-12-18 09:25:02,615 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221071: Failing over based on quorum vote results.
2023-12-18 09:25:02,620 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to artemis/10.0.4.2:61616 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2023-12-18 09:25:02,626 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to artemis/10.0.4.2:61616 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2023-12-18 09:25:02,739 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221037: ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0 to become 'live'
2023-12-18 09:25:03,084 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
2023-12-18 09:25:03,085 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
2023-12-18 09:25:03,089 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2023-12-18 09:25:03,089 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
2023-12-18 09:25:03,410 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2023-12-18 09:25:03,421 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2023-12-18 09:25:03,427 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5445 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]
2023-12-18 09:25:03,429 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5672 for protocols [AMQP]
2023-12-18 09:25:03,431 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:1883 for protocols [MQTT]
2023-12-18 09:25:03,433 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61613 for protocols [STOMP]
2023-12-18 09:25:22,407 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@6a020ca [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.5a3ee128-9d87-11ee-8db6-0242ac120004, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.5a3ee128-9d87-11ee-8db6-0242ac120004, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@a0a70bd targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@6a020ca [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.5a3ee128-9d87-11ee-8db6-0242ac120004, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.5a3ee128-9d87-11ee-8db6-0242ac120004, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@a0a70bd targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=artemis], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@2015092867[nodeUUID=2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=-1&host=null, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=artemis], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
```

Answer (score 1):

When the primary broker is restarted it looks like the journal that it originally had is now gone which means it creates a new journal and initializes it with the brand new node ID. Since this node ID doesn't match the node ID of the backup then fail-back won't occur. Instead the two brokers just cluster together.

Let's walk through the relevant log entries...

First, when the backup starts:

```
AMQ221024: Backup server ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0 is synchronized with live server, nodeID=2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403.
```

Notice the node ID is `2a076f68-9d87-11ee-9bd9-02420a000403`. This node ID would have come from the *original* primary.

However, when the primary is restarted it logs:

```
AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.31.2 [0.0.0.0, nodeID=d0fdfaf5-9d89-11ee-a30d-0242ac120004]
```

Notice the node ID is `d0fdfaf5-9d89-11ee-a30d-0242ac120004` which doesn't match the node ID of the (now active) backup. This indicates the primary broker's journal (including the node ID) was lost and recreated. Since the node IDs are different they won't pair together.

You need to find a way for the broker's to keep their journals even when they are restarted. The journal contains state information (i.e. the node ID) which is critical for replication use-cases.

Comment: thanks Justin but that a container crashes and all memory is lost should be supported. can we hardcode the nodeid or similar?

Comment: There is currently no way to hard-code the nodeID which may seem odd, but folks have just always used persistent journals. I've opened [ARTEMIS-4545](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4545) to implement this.

Comment: great initiative Justin!

Answer (score -2):

Looks like there might be an issue with the configuration of your ActiveMQ Artemis setup in Docker Swarm, particularly in how the master and slave nodes are configured to connect to each other. The logs indicate that the backup (slave) is not allowing the failover to happen.

Here are a few things you can check:

**Networking and DNS Resolution:**

Ensure that the containers can reach each other using their service names (artemis and artemis-slave).
Check if DNS resolution is working within the Docker Swarm network. You might want to add an entry in each container's /etc/hosts file for the other container.

**Cluster Connection Configuration:**

Verify that the cluster-connection configuration in both broker-artemis-master.xml and broker-artemis-slave.xml is correct.
Make sure the connectors are properly configured, and the addresses match the service names used in Docker Swarm.

**Firewall Rules:**

Ensure that there are no firewall rules blocking communication between the master and slave containers.

**HA Policy Configuration:**

Double-check the  setting in the broker-artemis-master.xml. It should be set to true to allow the master to take back control once it is available.

**Check for Split Brain Issues:**

The log mentions a possible split brain issue. Investigate the network setup to prevent this. You might want to configure the votes attribute in your broker.xml files to ensure a clear decision during a failover.

**Live Server Disconnection:**

Ensure that the live server (artemis) is properly shut down when you stop it. The logs indicate a connection issue, possibly due to an abrupt termination.

**Connection Configuration:**

The logs also show a warning related to connection failure with artemis/10.0.4.2:61616. Verify that the artemis and artemis-slave hostnames are correctly resolved.

**Docker Swarm Constraints:**

Double-check the Swarm node constraints to ensure that the containers are placed correctly on manager and worker nodes.

**Container Logs:**

Examine the logs of both the master and slave containers for any additional error messages or warnings that might provide more insight.

**Version Compatibility:**

Ensure that the ActiveMQ Artemis versions used in both containers are compatible with each other.
After making these checks, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue preventing the failover from happening successfully.

Comment: I have updated regarding firewall rules, all TCP and UDP ports are open. From inside the container I can see that nodes can ping eachothers names: artemis, artemis-slave. The containers are running one on each node. I'm wondering if there needs to be any additional config related to the cluster. this is not clear from docs. Tried to keep this as simple as possible.